# Making a small VHDL script that outputs a 1(5v) for 2 seconds when a 1 is inputted, but then goes back to a zero

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to make a program to power a dc motor for 2 seconds when a 1 is inputted. I already have a circuit designed with an LED and a capacitor for the motors protection, but i can't figure out a way to make this VHDL script.

if i try to use a "wait" statement or something, it conflicts with my "if" statements. This is for a cyclone IV FPGA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're question is not answerable - you have provided no code. You need to write a [MCVE] with a clear indication of the step that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The "wait" statement is not synthesizable.
This means, you will not be able to run it on any board. It is more like a "helping" tool for modelling - e.g. when you need to model the real time delays of flipflops or make a testbench.
The easiest way to create a time delay on your board is to create a counter, that counts up to a given value and changes signal/output when value reached.